# .NET Uninstaller Registry Rights

Tags: c#, vb.net, deployment, registry, uninstallation

I am writing a custom Windows setup program and all has gone well to this point.  I have working code that allows the program being installed to show in the Windows “Add/Remove Programs window.  When I attempt to uninstall the program in the normal way from the Add/Remove Programs window I get an error, “You do not have sufficient access to uninstall [my program name]…. After some digging I concluded I need to grant privileges to the key …/uninstall/[my program name].  I put together some code in an attempt to grant privileges but it does not work.  What am I doing wrong? I have included my code in “obsolete” VB below.
Thanks for helping me.

Code:

Private Sub TestKeys()

```
    Dim registrySearchKey As RegistryKey

    registrySearchKey = RegistryKey.OpenBaseKey(RegistryHive.LocalMachine, RegistryView.Registry32).OpenSubKey("SOFTWARE") _
                        .OpenSubKey("Microsoft").OpenSubKey("Windows").OpenSubKey("CurrentVersion").OpenSubKey("Uninstall")

    For Each ValueName In registrySearchKey.GetSubKeyNames

        If ValueName = "TimeTracker" Then

            Dim registryKeyToAlter As RegistryKey
            registryKeyToAlter = registrySearchKey.OpenSubKey("TimeTracker")

            Try

                Dim rs As RegistrySecurity = New RegistrySecurity()

                Dim user As String = Environment.UserDomainName & "\" & Environment.UserName

                rs.AddAccessRule(New RegistryAccessRule(user, RegistryRights.WriteKey, InheritanceFlags.ContainerInherit,
                                                              PropagationFlags.InheritOnly, AccessControlType.Allow))

                registryKeyToAlter.SetAccessControl(rs)

                MsgBox("Key Permission was set.")

            Catch ex As UnauthorizedAccessException
                MsgBox("Error: " & ex.Message)
            End Try

        End If

    Next

End Sub
```